# Unable to access path params

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I have the following:

```
<BrowserRouter>
   <Sidebar>
   <Switch>
       <Route path='room/:roomId' component={RoomComponent}/>
   </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Now inside the room component, if I console.log(this.props). I have access to the roomId param. However, inside the Sidebar component, I don't have access to the roomId param. If I console.log(this.props), my location and match props look like follows:

```
    location:
       hash: ""
       key: "6qujt0"
       pathname: "/room/asdf3/"
       search: ""
       state: undefined

    match:
       isExact: false
       params:{}
       path: "/"
       url: "/"
```

Do you have any idea, what could be happening? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only access that information within your `Route` `component` and its further children (if wrapped with `withRouter`).

What you could do is use the same matching code that `Route` uses with [matchPath](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/matchPath):

```
// inside your Sidebar component

import { matchPath } from "react-router";

const match = matchPath(this.props.location.pathname, {
  path: "/room/:roomId",
  exact: false,
  strict: false
});

// match should be:
//  {
//    isExact: false
//    params: {
//        roomId: "asdf3"
//    }
//    path: "/room/:roomId"
//    url: "/room/asdf3"
//  }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can define state variable `roomId` in your `RoomComponent` like

```
constructor(props){
super(props);

 this.state = {
    roomid: this.props.params.match.roomId
    }
}
```

and now pass this value to your `SidebarComponent` as props so it can access this value.

```
<SidebarComponent
   roomId = this.state.roomid
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

react-router-dom is passing those props :History, Location, Match.

react-router is only going to pass these props down to components that are actually used inside the Route. That is why RoomComponent has access to those props however Sidebar component is not going to access because Sidebar was not setup as a component value for a Route.

Answer (score 0):

Probably sidebar component doesn't have `withRouter`, but you can better use a function or a library to parse url queries, I'm always using query-string's parse function, here's an example:

```
import * as qs from 'query-string';

const { search } = history.location;
const query = qs.parse(search, { ignoreQueryPrefix: true });
console.log(query.roomId);
```

Comment: Hi Jose, the SideBar is wrapped in withRouter, that's how I have access to match, and location props. but the params object is empty. Aren't parsed path parameters a functionality provided by reac-router-v4? How come I have access to them inside the RoomComponent ? Thank you for you help

Answer (score 0):

That's because the Sidebar is not the child of the room component, it's sitting outside of the router, it will only get the root path as the closest match.

One solution will be saving the `match` object to the redux store and get it through the state.